# How to assign ID to TR generated by datalist/datagrid in asp.net?

Tags: html, asp.net, datalist

How can I set ID to `TabelRows` generated by `DataGrid/DataList`?
I want to assign a row id by myself to every row of `DataList`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attach a handler for the `ItemDataBound` event on your control:

```
<asp:DataGrid OnItemDataBound="myGrid_ItemDataBound" ...>
```

Declare the handler method like this:

```
protected void myGrid_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.Item.Attributes.Add("id", "some_id");
}
```

Comment: i have used like this :
 Protected Sub dljyotishpaid_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListItemEventArgs) Handles dljyotishpaid.ItemDataBound
        If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
            e.Item.Attributes.Add("id", "1")
        End If
    End Sub

Comment: @Raj: The C# version works fine here, and your VB translation looks fine to me. What problem are you facing? Any compile error or runtime exception?

Comment: no error or exception but when i see the viewsource of page its not showing me id their for TR

Comment: showing like this :
      <table id="ctl00_CPH1_dljyotishpaid" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tr>
   <td valign="top">

Comment: Did you remember to attach the event handler (first code sample in my answer)? If yes: try explicitly throwing an exception from the handler method to see if the method is ever invoked.

Comment: i have debugged... my debugger is going through these lines.. but i don't know why its not working

Comment: Does the debugger hit `e.Item.Attributes.Add("id", "1")` once for each row?